# What is the relationship between zero-product property and roots of polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let's consider the group $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ with the usual addition and multiplication by real scalars. Then, $\{1:=(1,0),i:=(0,1)\}$ is a basis, and any $z \in \mathbb{R}^2$ can be uniquely written as $z=x1+yi$.

The most general multiplication $\times$, such that:

1. $\times$ is distributive with $+$;
2. $1:=(1,0)$ is the neutral element for $\times$;
3. $i \times i=\alpha1+\beta i$

is given by:

$$(x_1,y_1 )×(x_2,y_2 ):=(x_1x_2+αy_1y_2,x_1 y_2+y_1x_2+βy_1y_2) \tag 1$$

Now, I note that the condition which ensures:

- the zero-product property to hold, and
- the equation $z^2+w=0$ to have solutions in $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\times)$ *whatever* the constant term $w$

is exactly the same, namely:

$$\beta^2+4\alpha<0 \tag 2$$

[The choice $(\alpha,\beta)=(-1,0)$, compatible with $(2)$, gives rise to $\mathbb{C}$, the field of complex numbers; but I don't think this is much relevant for my question hereafter.]

As I believe this is not a mere coincidence, my question is:

> What is the seemingly tight relationship between zero-product property and roots of polynomials?

Comment: what you are actuelly doing here is building a field extension of degree 2 (i.e. adjoining an irreducible polinomial of degree 2). that is why those polinomials pop up, so look into that and it should get clear quite fast!!!

Comment: You haven't told us what "the zero-product property" is.

Comment: Oops, sorry; I meant: $ab=0 \Rightarrow a=0$ or (not exclusive) $b=0$.

Comment: @amWhy, I think that your edit has changed the meaning of the OP: 1, 2 and 3 are required conditions on the multiplication *under construction*, which (conditions) lead to $(1)$.

Comment: I changed nothing in the conditions, nor (1).  I merely corrected a rejected edit that only took hyphens out of "zero-product".

Comment: @amWhy, not really, you added an "is" and an "and", which change the meaning.